# Zend_Db_Table - inserts after delete in transaction duplicate entry error

Tags: php, transactions, zend-db-table, duplicates

I'm developing a system in which I have an entity 'program' which has some 'locations' via a link table. I'm using Zend Framework with Zend_Db_Table.

location 1-----* programlocation *------1 program

In my mapper I have a function save() which should save the program:

```
public function save(Application_Model_Program $program)
{
    try
    {
        //start transaction
        $this->_getDbTable()->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();

        //make sure category is saved (has an id)
        $categoryMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_ProgramCategory();
        $categoryMapper->save($program->getCategory());

        $programData = array(
            'title'=>$program->getTitle(),
            'slug'=>$program->getSlug(),
            'description'=>$program->getDescription(),
            'dateFrom'=>$program->getDateFrom()->toString(self::DB_DATE_FORMAT),
            'dateTo'=>$program->getDateTo()->toString(self::DB_DATE_FORMAT),
            'category'=>$program->getCategory()->getId()
        );

        if($program->getId() === null)
        {
            $newId = $this->_getDbTable()->insert($programData);
            $program->setId($newId);
        }
        else
        {
            $where = $this->_getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id = ?", $program->getId());
            $this->_getDbTable()->update($programData, $where);
        }

        //save locations to program
        $programProgramLocationMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_Link_ProgramProgramLocation();
        $programProgramLocationMapper->saveLocationsToProgram($program->getLocations(), $program);

        //commit
        $this->_getDbTable()->getAdapter()->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        //rollback transaction
        $this->_getDbTable()->getAdapter()->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

The Application_Model_Mapper_Link_ProgramProgramLocation::saveLocationsToProgram method looks like this:

```
public function saveLocationsToProgram(
    array $locations,
    Application_Model_Program $program)
{
    $deleteWhere = $this->_getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteInto("program = ?", $program->getId());
    $this->_getDbTable()->delete($deleteWhere);

    foreach($locations as $location)
    {           
        $data = array('program'=>$program->getId(), 'location'=>$location->getId());
        $this->_getDbTable()->insert($data);
    }
}
```

My problem is an exception is raised in on the last shown insert statement "Mysqli statement execute error: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'". So it seems the delete statement before the inserts is not executed correctly. But the delete statement correctly returns the amount of entries deleted, and if I do a select after the delete the entries seem to be deleted correctly.

The same problem happens in a similar structure with tags to files.

I have no idea what's causing this and how to solve it, if any of you has it would be great as it's blocking the functionality of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug somewhere else in my application which caused the program `::$locations` array to contain duplicated items.